# Export resume in JSON Resume format

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I would like to be able to export my resume in [JSON Resume](https://jsonresume.org/) format. This would allow me to use tools like [HackMyResume](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hackmyresume) to easily edit it, and convert it to just about any format employers would want.

Comment: Would love to help write the export tool if there is any StackOverflow API's for it.

Comment: This seems a wish rather than a question in scope for this site. Please indicate what is the issue, what you tried, how to reproduce, etc. Read how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 9):

## JSON Resume export

There's not a *JSON Resume* specific export available as of March 2022.

And considering that the service is being discontinued in April 2022, it is unlikely that the team will ever get around to implementing such a feature.

## Regular JSON export

[developerstory.dev/stackoverflow](https://developerstory.dev/stackoverflow) can give you a *generic* JSON export.  It'll connect to your Stack Overflow account for gathering Developer Story data, then lets you download a JSON copy, or publish to a unique URL on developerstory.dev:

*(Disclaimer: I am the creator of developerstory.dev)*

1. Go to https://developerstory.dev/stackoverflow
2. Click "Import from StackOverflow"
3. Grant permission to login
4. Wait for the import to finish
5. Click "Or, download JSON"

[image: Screenshot of developerstory.dev with "Or, download JSON" circled]

[image: Screenshot of JSON data for Jess Telford's Developer Story]

Answer (score 3):

*Full disclosure - I created devstory.fyi*

#### JSON Resume Export

Here's a method to get **JSON Resume** format. All the fields from JSON resume spec are present, however, there are some extra fields as well. JSON Resume doesn't quite map 1:1 from SO story/CV so the extra fields are meant to preserve more data, rather than discard things that don't map exactly. Also, all html will be converted to markdown. You can view yours by:

1. Navigate to [devstory.fyi](https://devstory.fyi/users/story/preview?utm_campaign=launch&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social)
2. Enter the public URL to your story
3. Select "Download JSON"

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**How to download your developer story directly to your PC from Stack Overflow, without 3rd parties or sharing your profile name.**

It is possible to export your developer story as `.json` using the MAC format and docker in less than 5 minutes.

Use this command:

```
docker build -t getmanfred/dev-story-scraper https://github.com/getmanfred/dev-story-scraper.git#main && \
docker run -p3000:3000 -d getmanfred/dev-story-scraper && \
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/?username=<profile_user_name' -X GET > MAC.json && \
more MAC.json
```

Where `<profile_user_name>` should be your profile public user name.

It works like a charm and is based on the opensource parser version used by [Manfred](https://www.getmanfred.com/stackoverflowgeddon), but you don't have to use their front-end, so your user and data will remain unknown.

**Note**: *you should turn your profile public for the export to work.* Check next image for reference:

[image]

I think the solution is as simple as the one offered by Manfred, but with increased privacy. On any case, you also can go to [their web](https://www.getmanfred.com/stackoverflowgeddon) and download from there.

Full disclosure: I don't have any business relationship with Manfred. I like the opensource solution they created and shared without any cost with the community.