# Is there a CV API to get the data in JSON or XML format?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, api

For Career.stackoverflow.com, is there a CV API to get the data in XML format?  I don't need it for everyone, I just wanted it for mine.

I wanted to redo my CV using XSL:FO as a renderer.  JSON would also work, but I'd rather it be XML so I don't have to do the conversion to XML before I pass it to the XSLT engine.

Comment: Related request but then for a JSON format: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318637/export-resume-in-json-resume-format

Comment: FYI, the linked question has received an answer.